# How to implement a Record with a custom Type as its Key value without having to create a field for each Type?

Tags: typescript

I have a class that has a property `fruits` that is Record that maps a `Fruit` to an object.

```
type Fruit = 'Orange' | 'Apple' | 'Banana';

class FruitHandler {
  fruits: Record<Fruit, Object>; 
  constructor() { this.fruits = {} /* 1st error */ }
  
  public createFruit(fruit: Fruit): Object {
    if (this.fruits[fruit]) return this.fruits[fruit] /* 2nd error */
    
    const _fruit = new Object();
    this.fruits[fruit] = _fruit;
    return _fruit
  }
}
```

The issue I am having is that when I initialise the `fruits` property, I get the following error:

```
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Record<Fruit, Object>': Orange, Apple, and Banana.
```

If I change the property of `fruits` to be Partial, i.e. fruits: `Partial<Record<Fruit, Object>>`, I get a different when I try to return the object associated in the fruit:

```
Type 'Fruit | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Fruit'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Fruit'
```

I'm clearly not understanding something.

Would somebody be able to explain what it is that I am missing? And how I might be able to go about implementing what it is that I am looking for: a Record with varying number of values, without having to implement each and every Type that I have typed as its Key.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOR7zW)

*EDIT:*
I have a working - but not ideal - solution:

```
private fruits: Partial<Record<Fruit, Object>>;
...
public createFruit(fruit: Fruit): Object {
  if (this.fruits[fruit]) return this.fruits[fruit] as Fruit;
```

This has gotten rid of the error, but it obviously isn't something I want to do if it can be helped.

Comment: If you can add a link on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ for your code that would be great!

Comment: Why are you using `new Fruit()`? `Fruit` is a type, more specifically a union of strings. Even if you could use `Fruit` as a value, you can't use `new` on strings?

Comment: And if you annotate the function to return a `Fruit`, why are you returning any `Object` instead? `if (this.fruits[fruit]) return this.fruits[fruit]` - this is returning an Object if the fruit exists.

Comment: I suspect that you have tried to turn your real-world scenario into a simplified example, but the example has many errors in of itself that don't relate to the actual problem. Can you please correct these so that someone may answer the question? In its current state, the question is unanswerable as there are more problems than there are problems presented, making it difficult for us to determine what your intent was.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to create an object of `Fruit`. I have updated it now.

Comment: @LeoDog896 Good suggestion - I have added a link

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1pbyW) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  (Please mention @jcalz if you reply or I won't be notified)

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that works. Thanks a lot for your help. I don't think I've ever used `??` properly before. After seeing it here, I understand its benefit/how it got around the error I was having. Feel free to actually create an answer - I'll *check it off*. Thanks, again :)

Comment: Okay, I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want `fruits` to be a `Partial<Record<Fruit, Object>>` as opposed to a `Record<Fruit, Object>`.  [The `Partial<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) expresses a type where all the properties are [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties),

```
class FruitHandler {
  fruits: Partial<Record<Fruit, Object>>; // <-- need this
  constructor() { this.fruits = {} }
```

Now we have to figure out how to implement `createFruit()`.

---

The problem you're having is that the [truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) check for `this.fruits[fruit]` doesn't serve to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#truthiness-narrowing) the `this.fruits[fruit]` property.  Because the type of `fruit` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) and not a single literal type, it does not realize that both instances of `this.fruits[fruit]` necessarily refer to the same value.  The type system cannot tell the difference between `if (obj[k]) return obj[k]` and `if (obj[k]) return obj[p]` if `k` and `p` are of the same type.  If that type is a single string literal like `"a"`, then narrowing is fine no matter what... `if (obj.a) return obj.a` is obviously safe and good.  But if it's a union like `"a" | "b"`, then the compiler can't tell if you're writing `if (obj.a) return obj.b` or vice versa, and so it doesn't let you narrow.

There is a longstanding open issue about this at [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530).  For now, it's a missing feature.

The workaround here is to make sure you only do the property read exactly once, so the compiler doesn't see a potential for there being two different values.  The easy way to do this is to save the property to a new variable before testing, like this:

```
public createFruit(fruit: Fruit): Object {
  let _fruit = this.fruits[fruit];
  if (_fruit) return _fruit; // okay
  _fruit = new Object();
  this.fruits[fruit] = _fruit;
  return _fruit;
}
```

By saving the property you read into `_fruit` to start with, now you can write `if (_fruit) return _fruit` and the truthiness narrowing succeeds.

That works, but if you want a terser implementation you could refactor to use [the nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

```
public createFruit(fruit: Fruit): Object {
  return this.fruits[fruit] ?? (this.fruits[fruit] = new Object());
}
```

This is essentially the same thing; if `this.fruits[fruit]` isn't `undefined` or `null` then you return it.  Otherwise, the [assignment expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) is evaluated which both assigns the new object to the property and returns that object.

The compiler recognizes the above as safe, since the type of `x ?? y` is something like `NonNullable<typeof x> | typeof y`, which in this case will be `NonNullable<Object | undefined> | Object` which is `Object | Object` which is `Object`.

You can verify that this behaves as expected from the caller's side as well:

```
const x = new FruitHandler();
const b = x.createFruit("Banana"); // CREATED
console.log(b); // {}
const b2 = x.createFruit("Banana"); // not created
console.log(b === b2) // true
console.log(x.fruits.Orange) // undefined
const o = x.createFruit("Orange"); // CREATED
console.log(x.fruits.Orange) // {}
const a = x.createFruit("Apple"); // CREATED
console.log(a); // {}
console.log(a === b) // false
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigcgPJwIYB2A5hJlAD5YCCYYANqRVgEKFuYDcAsAFC8DGdPAGdhsRCgAShACYM4UAN68oUAGYTgwgFxQACnjjAkeOgB4AShH4B7ODLPxkwADRRsAIwBW14AD4-bh5VWwJhYER+YDsACgBKJShgAAskYQA6DWcxDEUAXyg83hUoMAQPOiR+KH44CDxgCCcUbABrPBAYrJRdZuA43U8fKKUS1QZUAH1u1AwUtMzNYQBtGYBdINVVJDUoGOnNBLrgBDgCKAPnTa3LlHQoAggAd3dvX3jr1XmMmZX1+9uwE+UGOp3OgOuRT4wVK5Uq1Vq9UafS6ml6h0GbxGyhhqlBZySqR+S1WmjWUAA-BS9t9FtlSc5yRhHi8hu84nFIbwocUeKFwlAAB73FniZzSAhyCBwD4CGxhVAee6C9KIhpNTQxABErAIbC1nKgAHojVAAMIWACiVAAKpaACJysI2BjpOg2IgxDyGk1KKH8xUAJmVqrq6pROrYeoNHGNpoINlQasaMidwhdEDdHq96DQGA8gYSvoiCAgaYzWc9Kt+6VwhBIRdNCElEDUSEeqb58oFNhDyY1zm1deIEBjcfNVttDvLrvdVbpKAyw4b4-yadQeD7YeRmq1NHoo59pot1rtjq7ztn2bwR79M8zc5im7z+cb6lMwggQA)